# Serialize returns empty value

Tags: jquery, forms

Why jQuery serialize returns an empty value?

This is the HTML + JS code:
http://jsfiddle.net/nhGcq/

The code is easy, just:

```
alert($("#frm").serialize())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is serialized because your inputs don't have a `name` attribute. Give them one. This name is the key in the URL type string, that's why it's necessary.

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) :

> For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string,
>   the element must have a name attribute.

To automatically generate a name for your inputs, you could do something like this :

```
$('#frm :input').attr('name', function(num,name){
    return name||this.id||('i'+num)
});
```

But if you don't know the name nor id of your inputs, it might be hard to use the serialized string.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't noticed that konckout didn't generated names for the inputs... I'll have to find out how to add them.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `name atrribute`.

That's why you are getting empty alert.

Answer (score 0):

None of your inputs have a `name` ...only form controls with `name` can be serialized or submitted

Answer (score 0):

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nhGcq/5/)

You have to set in your `<input>` tag the attribute `name=""` to pass it.. like this:

```
<input type="" name="" id="" />
```